# Can't find element by xpath with Selenium in extjs editable grid

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, datagrid

I'm trying to write a test in Java using Seleniu WebDriver that will click in particular cell in editable datagrid created with extjs and change existing value.This is how the grid look like:

```
<div class="x-panel-body x-grid-body x-panel-body-default x-layout-fit x-panel-body-default x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-bottom x-docked-noborder-left" id="DictionaryTerritoryCountryGridPanel-body" style="width: 1299px; left: 0px; height: 354px; top: 23px;">
<div id="gridview-3448" class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; margin: 0px; width: 1299px; height: 353px;" tabindex="-1">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" tabindex="-1" style="width: 1299px;" class="x-gridview-3448-table x-grid-table" id="gridview-3448-table">
        <colgroup><col style="width: 459px;" class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3442"></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col style="width: 153px;" class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3443"></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col style="width: 612px;" class="x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3444"></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col style="width:25px" class="x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3445"></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col style="width:25px" class="x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3446"></colgroup>
        <colgroup><col style="width:25px" class="x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3447"></colgroup>
        <tbody id="gridview-3448-body">
            <tr tabindex="-1" class="x-grid-row  x-grid-data-row" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="5" data-boundview="gridview-3448" id="gridview-3448-record-5">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3442 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">Nibylandia</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3443 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3444 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">###-###</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3445 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj terytoria" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_020_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td><td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3446 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj miasta" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_035_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3447 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Usuń kraj" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Favorites_049_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr tabindex="-1" class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row" data-recordindex="1" data-recordid="2" data-boundview="gridview-3448" id="gridview-3448-record-2">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3442 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">Polska</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3443 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3444 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">63-440</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3445 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj terytoria" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_020_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3446 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj miasta" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_035_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3447 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Usuń kraj" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Favorites_049_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr tabindex="-1" class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-selected  x-grid-data-row x-grid-row-focused" data-recordindex="2" data-recordid="60" data-boundview="gridview-3448" id="gridview-3448-record-60">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3442 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">USA</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3443 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3444 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3445 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj terytoria" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_020_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3446 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj miasta" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_035_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3447 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Usuń kraj" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Favorites_049_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr tabindex="-1" class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row" data-recordindex="3" data-recordid="7" data-boundview="gridview-3448" id="gridview-3448-record-7">
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3442 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">test</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3443 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">0</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3444 x-unselectable ">
                    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3445 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj terytoria" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_020_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3446 x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Edytuj miasta" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Map_035_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
                <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-3447 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell">
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on"><img data-qtip="Usuń kraj" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   " src="img/Favorites_049_16x16.png" alt=""></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to edit this cell:

```
<td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-3442 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable ">
    <div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on">USA</div>
</td>
```

At first I wrote this code:

```
WebElement datagridcell = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(div,'USA')]"));
datagridcell.click();
for (int i = 0; i < datagridcell.getText().length(); i++) {
    datagridcell.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
}
datagridcell.sendKeys("Poland");
```

But nothing changed(altough during test compilance I see that Selenium click in the cell but nothing else happens).

I realized that after clicking in the cell xpath(of the cell) changed to something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:left;" class="x-grid-cell-inner" unselectable="on" id="ext-gen6622">&nbsp;</div>
```

I used google to search what `&nbsp;` mean(non-breaking space). But I still couldn't select this cell using Selenium.

My last code looks like this:

```
WebElement datagridcell = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//div[text()='USA']"));
datagridcell.click();
WebElement emptydatagridcell =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//div[text()='${nbsp}']"));
for (int i = 0; i < datagridcell.getText().length(); i++) {
    emptydatagridcell.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
}
emptydatagridcell.sendKeys("Poland");
```

But I getting error that Selenium can't find element by this xpath.

Maybe someone had this problem before I can send me some hint. Thanks !

Comment: So this grid changes the values frequently ?

Comment: Well, it's only changing value temporary( from 'USA' to '&nbsp;') when I'm clicking in the cell.